# Wildcard subdomain to subfolder in another subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect sudomains to subfolders with a .htaccess

**Working:**
subdomain.example.com -> example.com/subdomain ✓

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I want to rewrite the subdomain in another subfolder:

**Working, but with a redirect:**
subdomain.example.com -> example.com/subfolder/subdomain ✓

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://example.com/subfolder/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Not Working:**
subdomain.example.com -> example.com/subfolder/subdomain x

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  subfolder/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Why cant i add another subfolder? The subfolder is defenitely available (redirect working)

Comment: Why do you claim you "can't"? What does that mean? What happens if you do it?

Comment: I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this rule for subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/subfolder/\1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```